# How do I install node-sass with npm and nvm?

Tags: node.js

I'm having major difficulties installing node-sass on Mac OS X High Sierra.

I do have nvm installed.  NPM version v6.14.1

When I install node-sass I get Error:

```
 Missing binding /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin- 
 x64-48/binding.node
 Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS 
 X 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

 Found bindings for the following environments:
 - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 9.x
```

I've run npm rebuild node-sass --force and it still continues to happen.

Comment: Looks like it's trying to get you to update nodejs to 9.x. You might either have to do that or specifically install a legacy version of node-sass that works with node 6.x

Comment: Node-sass has specific NodeJS version requirements; you must use a version compatible with your NodeJS version.

Comment: wow.. that fixed it. install node v9.9.0 --- 5 horus wasted.  thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

I did the installation with *yarn* but had to go through a lot of errors. What helped, (after trying various tricks, like *npm rebuild node-sass* or deleting *$HOME/.node-gyp*), was to run the command with root permission:

> **sudo** yarn add --dev node-sass.

In your case it would be:

> **sudo** npm install node-sass

Hope it helps!